# Show field depending on specific weight value - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, field

I have a custom twig template and within it I have a div that I only want to display if the value of another field on the page (weight) is -5.

I know how to show the field if there is a 'value' but im not sure how to write it for a specific value...?

What I have now:

```
{% if node.field_position_on_page.value %}
<div class="profile-pic">
    {{ content.field_profile_picture }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I need it to be something like *none.field_position_on_page[-5]* but im not sure on the correct way to write that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `{% if node.field_position_on_page.value == -5 %}` will compare the field to your specific value.